# Run Process in thread MVC ,NET core

Tags: c#, .net

l have  `OraConn.ExecuteNonQuery(sql)` which is calling  oracle procedure  now l want to run it in background by using threading

So, how i can do this in my code below

```
public void Row_Inserted(OrderedDictionary rsold, OrderedDictionary rsnew) {

                //ew_Write("Row Inserted");
                //ghalib

                 string theMONTH = rsnew["MONTH"].ToString();
                            string theYEAR = rsnew["YEAR"].ToString();
                            if (theMONTH.Length < 2)
                            {
                                theMONTH = 0 + theMONTH;
                            }
                            int ReadingDate = Convert.ToInt32(theYEAR + theMONTH);
                            int myReadingType = Convert.ToInt32(rsnew["READING_TYPE"].ToString());
                            if (myReadingType == 1)
                            {
                                var OraConn = ew_GetConn();


                                string sql = "CALL READING_DATA(" + ReadingDate + ")";
                                OraConn.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);


                                }
                            else if (myReadingType == 2)
                            {
                                var OraConn = ew_GetConn();

                                string sql = "CALL GetData()";
                                OraConn.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
                            }
            }
```

Comment: If you just want it asynchronous try this: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OraConn.ExecuteNonQuery(sql));`

Comment: I don't know what API you are using. But you may have an `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` method, so look into that. Otherwise, `Task.Run` is your way to run a method on the ThreadPool. If you expect it to be long running, you might need to specify that using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`

Comment: dear my question is not duplicated !!

Comment: @ghalib You have a function that you need to run in the background, there are tons of answers for that on StackOverflow. One of them is in the link provided. `Task task = Task.Run((Action) Row_Inserted); await task;` you need to look at the `async/await` combination and follow that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx